# get product collection for specific ids in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products

I've got a list of product ids and I want to load a product collection for the list:

```
$getdata[$a]=Array
(
[0] => 166
[1] => 166
[2] => 164
);
 $_productCollection =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()                               
     ->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => $getdata[$a]))              
                               ->load();
```

I am getting error as 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /var/www/magento//app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
$getData= array(166,167,164);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=> $getData));
$productCollection->load();

echo count($productCollection);
```

Make sure your array `$getData` bellow format

```
$getData= array(166,167,164);
```

and above array output like

```
Array ( [0] => 166 [1] => 167 [2] => 164 )
```

Comment: var_dump($getdata[$a] gives me string(7) "166,166,164"

Comment: you must be pass in array format

Comment: first you convert str to array for eg. $getdata[$a] =  "166,167,164";
$getdata[$a] = explode(",",$getdata[$a]); and after pass in 

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=> $getdata[$a]));
$productCollection->load();

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with:

```
$getdata[$a] = array
(
    [0] => 166,
    [1] => 166,
    [2] => 164
);
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()                
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $getdata[$a]))
```

Comment: when i use this code it doesn't show any product

Comment: Also, there is an error in creating `$getdata` array. Check updated answer and try

Answer (score 1):

You  filter by 'entity_id' not 'id'

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'
                     $getdata[$a]))->load();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer when I use **id**  instead of **entity_id**  it throws same error

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the above answers. 
Change *entity_id* to *id*. It worked for me in Magento 1.7.0.1

```
   ->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));


$products->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(entity_id,'".implode(',',$productIds)."')");

foreach($products as $product)
{
    echo $product->getEntityId();
    echo $product->getSku();
}
```

Comment: @zest try above code